# How to get OpenCl 1.2 for AMD RX580 on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: amd-graphics, gpu, opencl

Any ideas how to get OpenCl 1.2 for AMD RX580 on Ubuntu 18.10?
I try to install amdgpu-pro from AMD site, but installation was failed...
P.S. Need OpenCl 1.2 for Davinci Resolve 15.